# Passing json as a String

Tags: java, json, string

For a Json body like

```
{
    "firstName": "hello",
    "lastName": "abc"
}
```

I am writing as

```
JSONObject body = new JSONObject();

    
body.put("firstName", "hello");
body.put("lastName", "abc");
```

and then converting body to string to pass it as string parameter

How can I write the same for body with response like

```
{
    "class": {
        "firstName": "hello",
        "lastName": "abc"
    }
}
```

I need to convert json to string afterwards

Comment: If you have well defined structure for your json. Then you might want to go with the class approach. It would make it a lot easier and flexible for changes in the future. Make a class with the properties you want, annotate them with the proper annotation. User objectMapper to convert the resultant class to string.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick

```
    JSONObject innerBody = new JSONObject();
    innerBody.put("firstName", "hello");
    innerBody.put("lastName", "abc");

    JSONObject outerBody = new JSONObject();
    outerBody.put("class",innerBody);
```

Comment: That's Great. Can you accept this as answer. And upvote so that others can also be benefited

Answer (score 0):

Create a class:

```
public class DataSource {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    //Constructor, getter, setter
}
```

And then:

```
JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
DataSource data = new DataSource();
data.setFirstName("bla");
data.setLastName("bla bla");
body.put("class", data );
```